# Need duplicate xmlns:xsi declaration in child element

Tags: xslt, namespaces

Can't get this working.
Running a xml to xml xslt-transformation.

Want this to be included in AppHdr as well (requirement of receiver of xml output):

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Sample of xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Env:RequestPayload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:Env="urn:xxxxx:xxxxx:xsd:benvelope" xsi:schemaLocation="xyz IBenvelope.xsd">
        <AppHdr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:xxx:std:xxx:xxxxx:eee:xsd:hhh.01" xsi:schemaLocation="abc.xsd">
        </AppHdr>
        <Document xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        </Document>
    </Env:RequestPayload>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Env:RequestPayload xsi:schemaLocation="xyz IBenvelope.xsd" xmlns:Env="urn:xxxxx:xxxxx:xsd:benvelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AppHdr xsi:schemaLocation="abc.xsd" xmlns="urn:xxx:std:xxx:xxxxx:eee:xsd:hhh.01" />
    <Document xmlns="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
</Env:RequestPayload>
```

Comment: It might be easier to fix the target application so it understands that namespaces are inherited than to fool your XSLT processor to output a redundant namespace declaration.

Comment: um, so you want the xmlns:xsi attribute repeated in the AppHdr? Semantically it is obviously superfluous because the namespace declaration from Env:RequestPayload still applies to the AppHdr child

Comment: Yes, I agree. 
But unfortunately I have no chance to affect the requirements.

Comment: So if any have a solution it would be very appreciated.

Comment: It's not going to be achievable with XSLT, you're going to have to do some custom post-processing. Try to convince your recipient that using XML is a good idea but you only get the benefits it you use it properly.

Comment: The kind of tomfoolery you might indulge in to satisfy your recipient might be to generate a declaration of xmlns:xsi99999="http://....." on the AppHdr element, and then do a textual replacement on the serialized output to replace xsi99999 with xsi.

Comment: pipe the xslt output thru `sed 's@<AppHdr @<AppHdr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'@g'`

Comment: Thank you all for answers. 
I have tried to get an answer from the recipient (surprisingly one of the biggest Central Securities Depository system in northern europe) why they require repeated attribute. Still no answer.
Previously used XMLNAMSPACES and XMLATTRIBUTE (SQL) to generate  the outbound XML, were it was possible to repeat the attribute. Now we are going to use XSLT.
Ok, anyway. In the meantime I have to rely on post-processing.

Comment: As the problem is outside of the problem that xslt is meant to solve, I see it as kind of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so there might be the need to step back - syntactically modifying the xml as well as approaching the requestor of the feature might both be appropriate.